# Get all widgets under cursor

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5

The `widgetAt` function gives me the widget directly under the cursor, at the highest z-order.

```
pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
widget = QtGui.qApp.widgetAt(pos)
```

But how can I get *all* widgets under the cursor? Including those behind the top-most one? Something like:

```
pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
widgets = QtGui.qApp.widgetsAt(pos)
```

#### Example

As an example of use, picture an overlay which adds animated graphics, like ripples on the surface of water, wherever the user clicked. Naturally, the overlay would need to receive and respond to clicks, but it must do so without interfering with clicks propagating to widgets underneath it.

Another example is usage tracking; to intercept and record clicks for analysis, the same overlay can be used but this time nothing is drawn, only collected.

In both cases, if only one widget is getting the click event, I'll need a way of distinguishing what widgets reside underneath it so as to pass the event on.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another possible solution, calling the existing `QApplication.widgetAt` multiple times.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


def widgets_at(pos):
    """Return ALL widgets at `pos`

    Arguments:
        pos (QPoint): Position at which to get widgets

    """

    widgets = []
    widget_at = QtGui.qApp.widgetAt(pos)

    while widget_at:
        widgets.append(widget_at)

        # Make widget invisible to further enquiries
        widget_at.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        widget_at = QtGui.qApp.widgetAt(pos)

    # Restore attribute
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, False)

    return widgets
```

#### Example

[image]

```
class Overlay(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Overlay, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 50) }")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        print [w.objectName() for w in widgets_at(pos)]
        return super(Overlay, self).mousePressEvent(event)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setObjectName("Window")
window.setFixedSize(200, 100)

button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1", window)
button.setObjectName("Button 1")
button.move(10, 10)
button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 2", window)
button.setObjectName("Button 2")
button.move(50, 15)
overlay = Overlay(window)
overlay.setObjectName("Overlay")
overlay.setFixedSize(window.size())

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here is some output.

```
[u'Overlay', u'Window'] # Clicking an empty area
[u'Overlay', u'Button 1', u'Window'] # Button 1
[u'Overlay', u'Button 2', u'Window'] # Button 2
[u'Overlay', u'Button 2', u'Button 1', u'Window'] # Overlap
```

It looks like the results are O(1), with the added benefit of returning each widget in the order in which they overlap. It does however cause overlapping windows to flash (Windows 8) as their attribute is changed and restored.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but off the top of my head:  You'll need to cycle through all of your widgets and use their coordinates against the mouse coordinates.

If you want **O(1)**, you can do this but it will require more overhead, and you'll need to store the coordinates after each move.

I actually have a class that does this, as I want movable (by user) widgets to come up in their previous state, and I don't want to go through the hassle of coding this in all of my projects.

As such, I've subclassed `QDialog` (etc), and I add it to a convenience class which is essentially a glorified `QSettings` object.

When `QDialog` emits anything useful, the convenience class's slots will store those values (`geometry()`, basically) in `QSettings`.

For any project to use this behavior, a simple `ConvenienceClass::addWidget()` call w/ the `QWidget`, and a `QString` as an argument (as the key) and it's all stored under the sheets.

If you want to expand on this, you can store all of your `QWidget`'s coordinates in this convenience class, and simply grab them **O(1)** when you deem necessary.

The storing of the coordinates is trivial, as the work done to calculate them is done anyway. The convenience class which holds these isn't too difficult, but does add some complexity.

Comment: Unless something better comes along, I'll mark this as accepted soon. Ideally hoping for a more clean-cut solution that is of O(1) performance, as opposed to this which is O(n).

Comment: But I'm not doing any moves?

Comment: Okay... not sure what widget would be under another one (other than like a button on top of a dialog or a canvas or something).  In that case you'll have to grab it either right after it's show()'n or the linear approach as before.

Comment: Gotcha -- I think in this case, you might be able to store their coordinates as they are added (to the overlay).  Other than that, the O(n) approach is all I can think of.